# Index out of range error

Tags: terraform

I am fairly new to terraform and I have encountered an issue that I am unable to resolve.  This is the error message:

Error: Error refreshing state: 2 error(s) occurred:

- module.ssl-certificates.aws_route53_record.west_cert_validation: 1 error(s) occurred:
- module.ssl-certificates.aws_route53_record.west_cert_validation[104]: index 104 out of range for list local.west_dvo (max 104) in:

${lookup(local.west_dvo[count.index], "resource_record_name")} 
* module.ssl-certificates.aws_route53_record.east_cert_validation: 2 error(s) occurred:

- module.ssl-certificates.aws_route53_record.east_cert_validation[104]: index 104 out of range for list local.east_dvo (max 104) in:

${lookup(local.east_dvo[count.index], "resource_record_name")} 
* module.ssl-certificates.aws_route53_record.east_cert_validation[105]: index 105 out of range for list local.east_dvo (max 104) in:

${lookup(local.east_dvo[count.index], "resource_record_name")}

If i add an additional name to my default domain list, then the error goes away. Its as if the count.index is out of sync. Im not sure how to resolve this issue.

I'm sure there may be more details that I need to provide, so please do not hesitate to include them.

Thank you!

Comment: This error started after i removed a domain from my Amazon Cert manager manually from my AWS console.